# Adding to Navigation Bar to desired position

Tags: xcode, ipad, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I have app i want the button on navigation bar should be on desired position but it is not getting done i have found methods for rightBarButton and leftBarButton but i want this in the center of the navigation bar

```
    UIButton *settingsView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40,40)];
[settingsView addTarget:self action:@selector(SettingsClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[settingsView setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *settingsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:settingsView];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:settingsButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]

[arrayOfItems addObject:flexibleSpace];
[arrayOfItems addObject:theItemYouWantCentered];
[arrayOfItems addObject:flexibleSpace];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = arrayOfItems;
```